# Java GUI (SWING/AWT) - Empty Frame - Components not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jpanel

I'm trying to create (hand-coded) a GUI similair to the GUI shown below, however, only an empty frame shows.

Mock GUI:
[image]

I've used various layouts and SWING/AWT components to create the GUI and 4 JPanels which contain:

- mainPanel: Contains all the panels in it.
- listPanel: Contains the JTables, JLabels and the two JButtons
- infoPanel: Contains the JLabels, JCheckBox and JTextBoxes.
- addPanel: Contains the JLists and JButton

This is what I coded so far:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public void buildGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hotel TV Scheduler");

                JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
                listPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

                JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

                JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                mainPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                mainPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
                mainPanel.add(addPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                JTable chOneTable = new JTable();
                JTable chTwoTable = new JTable();
                JTable listTable = new JTable();

                JLabel ch1Label = new JLabel("Channel 1");
                JLabel ch2Label = new JLabel("Channel 2");
                JLabel listLabel = new JLabel("List");

                JButton rmvChOneButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");
                JButton rmvChTwoButton = new JButton("Remove Channel");

                listPanel.add(ch1Label);
                listPanel.add(ch2Label);
                listPanel.add(listLabel);
                listPanel.add(chOneTable);                
                listPanel.add(chTwoTable);
                listPanel.add(listTable);
                listPanel.add(rmvChOneButton);
                listPanel.add(rmvChTwoButton);

                JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title");
                JLabel genreLabel = new JLabel("Genre");
                JLabel durationLabel = new JLabel("Duration");
                JLabel actorLabel = new JLabel("Actor");
                JLabel directorLabel = new JLabel("Director");
                JLabel rentableLabel = new JLabel("Rentable");
                JLabel synLabel = new JLabel("Synopsis");

                JTextField txtTitle = new JTextField();          
                JTextField txtGenre = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDuration = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtActor = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtDirector = new JTextField();
                JTextField txtSynopsis = new JTextField();

                JCheckBox rentCB = new JCheckBox();

                infoPanel.add(titleLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtTitle);
                infoPanel.add(genreLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtGenre);
                infoPanel.add(durationLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDuration);
                infoPanel.add(actorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtActor);
                infoPanel.add(directorLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtDirector);
                infoPanel.add(rentableLabel);
                infoPanel.add(rentCB);
                infoPanel.add(synLabel);
                infoPanel.add(txtSynopsis);

                JButton btnAddProg = new JButton("Add Program");

                JList channelList = new JList();
                JList timeList = new JList();

                addPanel.add(btnAddProg);
                addPanel.add(channelList);
                addPanel.add(timeList);

                frame.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

Anyone can tell me why only an empty frame is showing up ?

Thanks and Regards,
Brian

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, no errors show up.

Comment: You never add mainPanel to the contentPane of the frame...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep just checked, you'll see something if you actually add the mainPanel to the frame, (looks nothing like the mock though!)

```
frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: ahhh !! Looks so different :(

Answer (score 3):

You've not added mainPanel to the frame